# New line in List

Tags: python, list, newline

Lets say I have a list called l1:
`l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
And I want to print it as
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
`[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
How would I do that in python on 3.9

I tried to us a \n, but that has not worked for me.

Comment: You want to print a list as multiple partial lists of a certain length - what have you tried yourself? You say you tried using a `\n`, which is to say you added the newline to the list and then tried print the list as a whole? Please share the code you tried, what you expected to happen and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(list[:5])
print(list[5:])
```

outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

if you want them to be printed on the same line then you can use:

```
print(list[:5],list[5:])
```

which will return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slicing would probably work for you.

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]    
print(l1[:5])    # print first half    
print(l1[5:])    # print second half
```

This should print both halves on separate lines, which is what I think you're trying to do with `\n`?

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```